# Underlining tex in Latex

Tags: arrows, rules, tcolorbox

I have the code of the line inserted under tex as below. I want to equate this straight line with words "My teacher" and I want to change the length of this straight line , so how to do this?
Please help me! Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1.8pt} O{3pt} O{brown}}{%
  \par\nobreak % don't break a page here
 \kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line
  \kern#2 % space before the rule
  {\color{#3}\hrule height #1 width\hsize} % the rule
   \kern#2 % space after the rule
   \nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule
    }

   \begin{document}
     lipsum[1]

     My teacher
     \hrule

      \end{document}
```

Out put

[image]

Comment: Did you mean "underlining **text**"? How about `\underline{My teacher}`? There are other options for underlining texts, offered by packages such as [`ulem`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/ulem/ulem.pdf) and [`soul`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/soul/soul.pdf).

Comment: do you perhaps mean to leave a blank underline so that a name can be filled in?  if so, then `\underline{\phantom{<some text long enough to leave the required space>}}` should work.

Answer (score 3):

This uses the basic `\box` width and depth and places the rule directly below the descender (if there's any) with `\dp\rulebox` etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1.8pt}mO{brown}}{%
\begingroup
\newbox\rulebox
\setbox\rulebox=\hbox{#2}
#2
\parskip=0pt\par%
\nointerlineskip
{\color{#3}\rule[-\dp\rulebox]{\wd\rulebox}{#1}}
\endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\myrule{My teacher}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with some option interface**
\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_tranhoang_options_prop
\keys_define:nn {tranhoang} {
  rulecolor  .code:n = {\prop_put:Nnn \l_tranhoang_options_prop {rulecolor} {#1}},
  rulewidth  .code:n = {\prop_put:Nnn \l_tranhoang_options_prop {rulewidth} {#1}},
  extraruleshift  .code:n = {\prop_put:Nnn \l_tranhoang_options_prop {extraruleshift} {#1}},  
}

\cs_new:Npn \retrieveadmindata #1 {
  \prop_item:Nn \l_tranhoang_options_prop {#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \SetupMyRule #1 {
  \keys_set:nn {tranhoang} {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{}+m}{%
  \begingroup
  \SetupMyRule{rulecolor=brown,rulewidth=1.8pt,extraruleshift=0pt,#1}
  \newbox\rulebox
  \setbox\rulebox=\hbox{#2}

  #2
  \par%
  \nointerlineskip
  \color{\retrieveadmindata{rulecolor}}\rule[\dimexpr-\dp\rulebox+\retrieveadmindata{extraruleshift}]{\wd\rulebox}{\retrieveadmindata{rulewidth}}
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\myrule[rulecolor=yellow]{My teacher}

\myrule[rulewidth=2pt,extraruleshift=-1ex]{My teacher}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How does this `\myrule` compare with what `soul` does with `\ul`? How does one compare?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It's another variant and does not need an additional package. Of course, I don't claim this to be breakable etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I wasn't asking “why do this when soul exists” :-) To be clear, I was genuinely curious about how the two approaches accomplish the same objective. Your approach I understand (and upvoted): you put the text (like “My teacher”) into a hbox called `\rulebox`, and add a `\rule` of width `\wd\rulebox` and depth `\dp\rulebox`. I was wondering what `soul` does, but probably on a comment on your answer isn't the right place to ask—I should read its documentation I guess!

Answer (score 1):

Or did you mean this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \ul{My teacher}


\end{document}
```

[image]